# Python networkx graph appears jumbled when drawn in matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, networkx

I am testing out how to create network graphs on "networkx"; my problem is that when I try plotting these graphs using "matplotlib", the nodes, edges, and labels appear jumbled. I want to have the labels attached to right node, and I want the edges to look like they are connecting the nodes.

## code

```
import networkx as nx
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
except:
    raise

g = nx.MultiGraph()

strList = ["rick james", "will smith", "steve miller", "rackem willie", "little tunechi", "ben franklin"]
strList2 = ["jules caesar", "atticus finch", "al capone", "abe lincoln", "walt white", "doc seuss"]
i = 0
while i < len(strList) :
    g.add_edge(strList[i], strList2[i])
    i = i + 1    

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g,pos = nx.spring_layout(g), nodelist = g.nodes())
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g,pos = nx.spring_layout(g), edgelist = g.edges())
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g,pos=nx.spring_layout(g))
#plt.savefig("testImage.png")
plt.show()
```

## image

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Xi6.jpg

I want my connections to be like this:

```
rick james <--> jules caesar
will smith <--> atticus finch
steve miller <--> al capone
...etc
```

Any help/insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spring layout is stochastic (random). One issue you're having comes from the fact that you are running this stochastic process a different time -- producing a different layout -- for the nodes, edges, and labels. Try this, where you compute the layout a single time:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos=pos, nodelist = g.nodes())
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos=pos, edgelist = g.edges())
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos=pos)
```

Or in the case that you don't need to style individual nodes/edges/labels:

```
nx.draw_spring(g)
```

---

I won't claim that this will give you a "good" layout because it doesn't (at least on my machine):

[image: spring-layout]

Maybe a [`networkx.draw_circular`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_circular.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_circular) layout would be a better fit:

```
nx.draw_circular(g)
```

[image: circular-layout]

You can read about all the NetworkX layouts [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html), including Graphviz (as suggested by @ThomasHobohm).

Comment: thanks alot. I have a followup question. The code I used to create the last image (circular one) is this: `LINE 1: pos = nx.circular_layout(g)
 LINE 2: nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos=pos)
 LINE 3: nx.draw_circular(g)
 LINE 4: plt.show()` is this the best practice/ will this always guarantee my labels and nodes will be aligned?

Comment: @RickJames: unless you are going to change the labels with `nx.draw_networkx_labels`, just use `nx.draw_circular`. But `nx.draw_circular` is not stochastic, so yes your nodes and labels will be aligned.

Comment: When I use `nx.draw_circular(g)` the labels are not included. Where would I indicate that I want the labels to be included?

Comment: @RickJames: what version of NetworkX are you using? By default they should be included with the latest version (1.9).

Comment: hmm I just checked the version and it is 1.9

Comment: @RickJames: strange. Try adding `with_labels=True`.

Comment: unfortunately still a no-go. I might try to reinstall networkx

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib is very bad at drawing readable graphs. I suggest you use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), at it's supported by NetworkX out of the box, and it let's you toggle way more settings with the dot format.