# Python networkx graph appears jumbled when drawn

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Note:

I already tried solution in
[Python networkx graph appears jumbled when drawn in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067998/python-networkx-graph-appears-jumbled-when-drawn-in-matplotlib)

But it didnt work. As you can see below, i placed the position in the end but still the graph appears to be jumbled.

Question:
I have a flow A->B->C->D->E->F->G->H. Generally the directed graph should form a circle. But despite lots of effort, i am not able to achieve desired result. Please find the below code and the output

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

refJourney = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
edgelis=[]
for i in range(len(refJourney)):
    edgesValue = refJourney[i:i+2]            
    if len(edgesValue)>1:
        edgelis.append((edgesValue[0],edgesValue[1]))
        
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edgelis, weight=0, length = 1)

val_map = {refJourney[0]: 1.0,
           refJourney[-1]: 0.5}
values = [val_map.get(node, 0) for node in G.nodes()]

edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['weight'])
         for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)])

plt.figure(3,figsize=(24,24)) 
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels)
nx.draw(G,pos,node_shape = 'D', node_color = values, node_size=15000,edge_cmap=plt.cm.Reds, font_color="whitesmoke", with_labels = True, font_size=10)
pylab.show()
```

[image]

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Generally the directed graph should form a circle.

That is not the lowest energy configuration for a path graph with a spring node layout. If you do want a circular node layout, there is `nx.circular_layout`. However, it (also) doesn't reduce edge crossings.

If you are open to using other libraries, `netgraph` works well in combination with `networkx` and does implement a circular layout with reduced edge crossings ([github](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph), [documentation](https://netgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Plot a path network with circular layout.
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

from netgraph import Graph, get_circular_layout # pip install netgraph

nodes = 'abcdefg'
edges = list(zip(nodes[:-1], nodes[1:]))
g = nx.Graph(edges)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
Graph(g, node_layout='circular', ax=axes[0])

node_layout = get_circular_layout(edges)
nx.draw(g, pos=node_layout, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am new to graph data, I have an upcoming project which I will need to use networkx. Any reference material/links/books  you can recommend I can go to and understand networkx

Comment: @wwnde In my experience, the bottleneck is always the lack of knowledge of core concepts & algorithms in graph theory & network analysis. Once you know what the problem is called, searching the networkx documentation for a solution is trivial. So I would focus my efforts on understanding the problem domain and figure out the exact networkx commands that you need as you go.